# 'ModuleNotFoundError' in python venv? I definitely have the module installed in the venv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-venv, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to use PIL in my project. I sourced my venv and then installed using pip3 install Pillow. I verified that the module is in fact installed but yet I am still getting the error.

```
pip3 list                                                                      
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.5.2
Django     4.1.1
Pillow     9.2.0
pip        22.2.2
setuptools 63.4.3
six        1.16.0
sqlparse   0.4.3
(env) mike@Mikes-MacBook-Air test_app % /Users/mike/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin/python /Users/mike/Desktop/bank_app/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mike/Desktop/bank_app/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I've tried reading through other posts with similar issues and saw someone mention that I could have an alias that is pointing to a different python location, could that be the issue? How would I resolve that?

Comment: Could you execute `$ which python3` on Terminal? Check if the path is the same as `/Users/mike/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/bin/python`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your virtual environment is activated

Command to activate virtual environment in linux an macOS:-

```
source venv_name/bin/activate
```

Command to activate virtual environment in windows:-

```
venv_name\Scripts\activate
```